# How can i redirect this page when php is executed

Tags: php, html

Problem is here. I want when the captcha is solved correctly to return to the same page in the same place where it display the message eg www.example.com#contact If i have missed anything or you need more information please let me know.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
    //your site secret key
    $secret = 'InsertSiteSecretKey';
    //get verify response data
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

    $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
    $email = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
    $message = !empty($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:'';
    if($responseData->success):
        //contact form submission code
        $to = 'codexworld@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'New contact form have been submitted';
        $htmlContent = "
            <h1>Contact request details</h1>
            <p><b>Name: </b>".$name."</p>
            <p><b>Email: </b>".$email."</p>
            <p><b>Message: </b>".$message."</p>
        ";
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
        //send email
        @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

        $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
        $name = '';
        $email = '';
        $message = '';
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
    endif;
else:
    $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
endif;
else:
$errMsg = '';
$succMsg = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$message = '';
endif;
?>
```

and then the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Using new Google reCAPTCHA with PHP by CodexWorld</title>
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
   <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
<div class="registration" id="contact">
    <h2>Contact Form</h2>
    <div class="avtar"><img src="images/color.jpg" /></div>
    <?php if(!empty($errMsg)): ?><div class="errMsg"><?php echo $errMsg; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($succMsg)): ?><div class="succMsg"><?php echo $succMsg; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="form-info">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="text" value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:''; ?>" placeholder="Your full name" name="name" >
            <input type="text" class="text" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:''; ?>" placeholder="Email adress" name="email" >
            <textarea type="text" placeholder="Message..." required="" name="message"><?php echo !empty($message)?$message:''; ?></textarea>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="InsertYourSiteKey"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
        </div>          
        <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Dont get it right, but lookup `header("Location: xyz.com/foobar.php");exit;` PHP redirect, if redirect is needed on server/php side. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php